# Object Oriented Design for generic hibernate object

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, pojo

I'm currently working good object oriented principles, and hibernate, I have this POJO, in which the properties would be dynamically populated. This is a design pattern I've read for good Object Oriented Design, in which it would be easy to add attributes to specificic object without breaking the application. **My question is, how can you map this to a table, when your attributes is supposedly dynamic**, I'm using an enum to limit the key value pairs for the map, but ideally it can still grow. I am only using in-memory database (h2) and I'm not going to be using the code for production use. This is for learning purposes only. see code below:

```
public class Transaction {

    private static Map<Object, Object> properties;

    public Transaction(){
        if(null != properties)
            properties = new LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>();
    }

    public Transaction(Map<Object, Object> properties){
        if(null != properties)
            setProperties(properties);
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<Object, Object> prop){
        properties = prop;
    }
    public void setProperties(Properties property, String value){
        properties.put(property, value);
    }

    public Map<Object, Object> getProperties(){
        return properties;
    }

    public String getProperties(Properties property){
        return (String) properties.get(property);
    }


}
```

So I want to be able to create a table that would have this properties, dynamically,
My Enum:

```
public enum Properties {
    Entry("Entry"), Id("Entry_ID"), Name("Name"), Credit("Credit");

    private final String description;

    private Properties(final String description){
        this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return description;
    }
}
```

**I have this hibernate mapping, but as you can see this would be need to be updated everytime a field is updated**, I need a generic mapping so that when I change/add the attributes, annotation or xml would be okay, see below:

```
 <class name="Transaction" table="TRANSACTION">
    <id name="id" column="ENTRY_ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name"/>
     <property name="credit" type="boolean" column="IS_CREDIT"/>
</class>
```

Comment: Note: the reason I have this mapping is because I started with the typical setters and getters for the object before trying to migrate to a map.

Comment: How will you create such a dynamic table ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UserDefinedField](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UserDefinedField.html) on Marin Fowler's web site may be a perfect starting point for exploring general answers to this question.

As for Hibernate: It's really designed for statically binding tables to objects and you may have significant problems if you change the schema while running. You can implement the following solutions, though:

- **Serialized LOB** (you serialize your Map into a binary field or - using JSON/XML - a text field). This is a half-and-half approach - half tabular/normal form/SQL and half not-SQL. So, if this approach is attractive, you might want to consider going all-in with a NoSQL database as discussed later
- **Attribute table**, where your customized attributes are stored in a key-value pair table that joins to to the master table. This can be mapped in Hibernate using [Indexed Collections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections-indexed) (see section 7.2.2.2 Maps) and you would end up with something quite like in your question:

  ```
  @Entity 
  public class Transaction {

      @Id @GeneratedValue public Integer getId() { return id; }
      public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
      private Integer id;

      // ... snip ...

      @OneToMany(mappedBy="transaction")
      @MapKey(name="name")
      public Map<String, String> getProperties(){
      return properties;
      }
      public void setProperties(Map<String, String> prop){
      properties = prop;
      }
      private Map<String, String> properties; // NB: Type has to be <String, String> because the column name is a String and you have defined the property value to be a String.

      public void setProperty(Properties property, String value){
      properties.put(property, value);
      }
      public String getProperty(String name){
      return (String) properties.get(property);
      }
  }

  @Entity
  public class Property {
      @Id @GeneratedValue public Integer getId() { return id; }
      public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
      private Integer id;

      @ManyToOne
      public Transaction getTransaction() { return transaction; }
      public void setTransaction(Transaction transaction) { this.transaction = transaction; }
      private Transaction transaction;

      public String getName() { return name; }
      public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
      private String name;

      public String getDescription() { return description; }
      public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }
      private String description;

  }
  ```
- **Pre-defined custom-fields**, where you start with a really wide table with loads of unused columns. In this implementation you end up defining a mapping between your arbitrary property names and the pre-defined column names (`getString1()`, `getString10()`, etc)

However, a much better solution for you may be to use a NoSQL database - specifically a document-based one. These allow you to store and retrieve arbitrary data-structures (maps and lists). Interestingly, using such an approach makes binding to the data store *significantly* easier.

[MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [Redis](http://redis.io/) (Java bindings at [Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis)) are examples.